# Intelliji Idea Cannot access org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, plugins, dependencies, swagger-2.0

I am setting up a springboot project in Intelliji Idea from a tutorial course, and having a problem with the message of "Cannot access org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin". I have read whatever I could pull out from google search, but with no luck and still getting stuck there. I attach the screenshot here and hope someone can help me out.

[image]

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: Yes, I ran "build project" and "build module", both said in event log "Build completed successfully with ..."

Comment: But in Maven window, under "org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core 1.2.0. RELEASE, all say "omitted for duplicate".

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I add `import org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin;` and then add to classpath.